# How to use a sub_query with a table that has soft delete?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a query and a subquery that looks like this:

```
// $query not included here
$query = $query->getQuery();
$subQuery = User::select('*')
    ->fromSub($query, 'sub_query')
    ->where($status, 'LIKE', '%' . $statusValue . '%')
    ->with($this->eagerLoadedRelationships)
    ->get();
```

But I get the following error: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.deleted_at' in 'where clause'`. When I remove `use SoftDeletes;` in my User model, it works fine. But I need that soft delete.

I tried `User::withoutTrashed()->select('*')...` but it's the same.

Is there a way for me to go around this?

I can't list the columns inside `select`. And I kinda have to use this sub query to check the results of the previous query (I can't add `where()` to the previous query).

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
$subQuery = User::select('*')
    ->fromSub($query, 'sub_query')
    ->where($status, 'LIKE', '%' . $statusValue . '%')
    ->whereNull('deleted_at')
    ->with($this->eagerLoadedRelationships)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Yes, that returns the results, but I don't need the deleted records here. Any way I can remove the deleted ones?

Comment: Oh, I added ::withTrashed(), and where('deleted_at', '=', null). If you add it to your answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $query->getQuery();

// Use "toBase()" to remove the global scopes from the subquery, including soft delete scope
$subQuery = User::select('*')
    ->fromSub($query->toBase(), 'sub_query')
    ->where($status, 'LIKE', '%' . $statusValue . '%')
    ->with($this->eagerLoadedRelationships)
    ->get();
```

By calling **toBase()** on the subquery, you are essentially getting the underlying Query Builder instance without any global scopes applied, including the soft delete scope. This should allow you to run the subquery without encountering the **"Column not found"** error related to **deleted_at**.

Answer (score 0):

To ignore Soft Deletes, use the withTrashed() method:

$user = User::where('name', $label)->where('group', $set)->withTrashed()->first();
This removes the default scope for the deleted_at column as it is applied when use SoftDeletes; is included for your model.